# Opening directory without knowing its name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory-listing

I'm writing a script in which user inputs the directory in which he wants to find a specific string inside .txt files, but I don't know how to open every directories inside the given directory without knowing their names.

For example this is a directory that the user specifies:

```
Project/
   AX/include/
             ax.txt
             bx.txt
   AX/src/
         ax.txt
         bx.txt
   BY/include/
             ay.txt
             by.txt
   BY/src/
         ay.txt
         by.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`grep -r`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to find strings in files recursively. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel. In your case run `grep -r "string to find" Project/`

That said, to list the folders inside a folder `path/to/folder/` you just need to let the shell expand it with globbing like this `ls path/to/folder/*/`. So you just need to run `yourcommand path/to/folder/*/`

Alternatively use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```bash
find path/to/folder/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec yourcommand {} + # or
find path/to/folder/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -z yourcommand
```

To do that in more levels use `find path/to/folder/ -type d -exec yourcommand {} +`, or `yourcommand path/to/folder/**/*/` after enabling [globstar](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) with `shopt -s globstar`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a python script for that, from os module of python you can use os.listdir which lists all the files inside a directory and you can iterate for directories inside the directory.

Code

```
import os
path = 'c:\\projects\\hc2\\'
folders = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for folder in d:
            folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))
for f in folders:
print(f)
```

Output

c:\projects\hc2\
c:\projects\hc2\analyzer\
c:\projects\hc2\analyzer\out\
c:\projects\hc2\analyzer\out\production\
c:\projects\hc2\analyzer\out\production\classes\
c:\projects\hc2\analyzer\out\production\classes\com\
//...